# Python - Converting Input Range Into Ordinal Characters

Tags: python, range, ordinal

Write a program that allows a user to type in two numbers, a lower bound and an upper bound, then prints all characters represented by the numbers between those bounds. Here is an example interaction:

```
Enter the lower ordinal bound: 60
Enter the upper ordinal bound: 70
The characters from 60 to 70 are: 
< = > ? @ A B C D E
```

This is the code we are currently learning- so I did not want to go outside of this with easier methods that we have not learned. With this, I get the range when I input 60 and 70. I need the answer to be converted to the ordinal values, instead of the actual numbers.

```
inputUpperOrdinal = input("Enter the lower ordinal bound: ")
inputLowerOrdinal = input("Enter the upper ordinal bound: ")

upperOrdinal = int(inputUpperOrdinal)
lowerOrdinal = int(inputLowerOrdinal)

ordinalNumbers = range(upperOrdinal, lowerOrdinal)

for char in ordinalNumbers:
    numValue = (char)
    print (numValue)
```

Comment: `[chr(i) for i in range(start,end+1)]`?

Comment: What is your question exactly? This is not a question. Please enounce a question and post with some code you wrote, as well as the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

for i in range(a, b):
   print(chr(i), end=' ')
```

Output:-

```
< = > ? @ A B C D E >>>
```